# QLPreviewController's tintColor is different the first time it is opened

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uinavigationbar, qlpreviewcontroller

The `tintColor` whenever I bring up the `QLPreviewController` is pink by default. I wanted it to be a specific color so I set it like so

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.hexStringToUIColor(hexStr: "202020")
```

This is what the method that brings up the `QLPreviewController` looks like

```
func openQLPreview() {
    quickLookController = QLPreviewController()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.hexStringToUIColor(hexStr: "202020")
    quickLookController.dataSource = self
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.quickLookController, animated: true)
}
```

[This is what it looks like the first time (after installing or closing and re-opening I open a document using the QLPreviewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4t7X.jpg)

[And this is what it looks like when I tap the back arrow and open the same document or any other document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UK9hB.jpg)

I want it to be the second color at all times, regardless of whether it is my first time calling `QLPreviewController` or not. It switches back to the pink whenever the app is terminated and re-launched.

**Edit (2/12/19)**
I have solved it. The reason it wasn't working because I was setting the tintColor before the `QLPreviewController` was pushed onto the `navigationController` stack therefore, it was setting the `tintColor` for the previous navigationItem in the stack (which is nothing because I am using a custom `navigationBar` throughout my app). So when `QLPreviewController` gets popped off the stack, and then pushed back in the next time I open a document, the `tintColor` remains from when I last set it.

```
func openQLPreview() {
    quickLookController = QLPreviewController()
    quickLookController.dataSource = self
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.quickLookController, animated: true)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.hexStringToUIColor(hexStr: "202020")
}
```

Therefore, simply setting the tintColor using `UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor` after `QLPreviewController` has been pushed, fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@IBOutlet weak var m_NavBar: UINavigationBar!

func openQLPreview() 
{
    quickLookController = QLPreviewController()
    m_NavBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.hexStringToUIColor(hexStr: "202020")
    quickLookController.dataSource = self
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.quickLookController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I'm not using IB for the QLPreviewController or navigation bar; tt has been done programmatically.